# How can I display a simple table in a report in Amazon Quicksight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight

I've been evaluating amazon quicksight recently, and it doesn't look like there is a way to create a report that contains a simple table of data.  While I expect I'll mostly be using it to create visualizations, I do also want some simple tables in my reports/dashboards as well.  Did I miss something / is there a way to create a simple table in Quicksight?

Note that the pivot table option provided in quicksight is not really what I'm looking for (they're intended for comparing things in a matrix, not so much for just displaying data), and also that I want to be able to display a table in an analysis/dashboard, not in the data-import view you get when uploading data to quicksight.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to create "tables" - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/tabular.html

> To create a non-aggregated view of the data, add fields only to the
>   Value field well. This shows data without any aggregations.
>
> To create an aggregated view of the data, choose the fields you want
>   to aggregate by, and then add them to the Group by field well.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do right now is make a small table of 5 columns or less using a pivot table.

- Drag a field into the visual
- Change the type to pivot table [See pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfO9l.png)
- Then you can add up 4 more fields in the `Rows` group. After that any more you drag will replace the others.